# FOSUserBundle authenticate selected user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I would authenticate a user in a very direct way (FOSUserBundle, Symfony2.2). I'am trying with a trivial example, but it doesn't work:

```
...
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController as RegController;
...
class DefaultController extends Controller{
...
public function indexAction(){
$route = 'first_set_profile';
$url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
$response = new RedirectResponse($url);
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$userToLogIn = $userManager->findUserByEmail('aa@bb.com');
new RegController(authenticateUser($userToLogIn, $response));
...
}
```

This script is running, but it is not authenticate the user with email aa@bb.com...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can authenticate a demo user for example programmatic:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

public function demologinAction(Request $request)
{
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    $user = $userManager->findUserByEmail('demo@example.com');

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No demouser found!');
    }

    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());

    $context = $this->get('security.context');
    $context->setToken($token);

    $router = $this->get('router');
    $url = $router->generate('dashboard_show');

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

The third parameter in the `UsernamePasswordToken` must be the firewall name.